# Weblogic Corba Remote API ACCESS "datatype java.lang.String and java.lang.Character printing 0X00"

Tags: weblogic, corba, iiop

We are having a REST API inside weblogic that internally connects to Corba Server. API response object comes with '0X00' in Datatypes java.lang.String and java.lang.String.Character. Remaining all datatypes are fine with correct data.

This is happening only in Weblogic 12C. Tomcat and Standalone Java class working fine as expected
Some thing related to Weblogic that client delegates not able to convert "String  and Character" datatype.

Weblogic Version - 12.2.1.4

JDK version - JDk 1.8_251

Answer (score 1):

We have found the root cause. Its because of "Corba delegate implementation". Need to explicitly specify JDK specific corba implementation class in corba init.

```
System.getProperties().put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl");
```

Otherwise Vendor specific delegates. In our case weblogic specific delegates(JDK 8) are implemented and is conflicting with server JDK 11 response.